# All of the sudden i get "Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have a SharePoint public site branded and it was working fine when out of the sudden the slider with images stopped appearing and I get this error :

Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference

[image: Error Message]

I have searched to find where this split function is referenced and I located it in the slider.txt file I have for the pages :

```
<script src="/../style library/mystyles/JS/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/../style library/mystyles/JS/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/../style library/mystyles/JS/slides.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/../style library/mystyles/css/global.css">
<script>
      var j =jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function () {
        j().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: "Pictures",
            CAMLRowLimit: 6,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                var hasRows = false;
               j(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function () {
                    hasRows = true;
                    var _url = '/' + j(this).attr("ows_RequiredField")
                    var _title = j(this).attr("ows_Description");
                     ***var blog = ($(this).attr("ows_blog")).split(",")[0];***

                    _slideDiv = j("<div class='slide'/>");
                    _link = j("<a href='"+ blog +"'  src='" + _url + "'/>");
                    _Image =j("<img  id='slideShowImage' src='" + _url + "'/>");
                  j(_link).append(_Image);
                    _slideDiv.append(_link);

                    _Title = j("<div class='caption1'><p>" + _title + "</p></div>");
                    _slideDiv.append(_Title);

                    j(".slides_container").append(_slideDiv);
                });
            }
        });
    });


    j(function () {
        j('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: '/../style library/mystyles/images/loading.gif',
            play: 5000,
            pause: 2500,
            effect:'slide',
             slideSpeed:100,
            hoverPause: false,
            animationStart: function (current) {
                j('.caption1').animate({
                    bottom: -35
                }, 100);
                if (window.console && console.log) {
                    // example return of current slide number
                    console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                };
            },
            animationComplete: function (current) {
                j('.caption1').animate({
                    bottom: 0
                }, 200);
                if (window.console && console.log) {
                    // example return of current slide number
                    console.log('animationComplete on slide: ', current);
                };
            },
            slidesLoaded: function () {                      
                j('.caption1').animate({
                    bottom: 0
                }, 200);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="example">
        <div id="slides">
            <div class="slides_container" id="slides_container_div">
            </div>          

         <a class="prev" href="#" ><img src="/../style library/mystyles/images/left-arrow.png"/></a>
                      <a class="next" href="#"><img src="/../style library/mystyles/images/right-arrow.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help me out to fix this? I haven't changed anything for a long time and this appeared recently.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Try this in the console `console.log(j(this).attr("ows_blog"));`

Comment: I have tried it and I get undefined . This means that It can't find the value ows_blog ? Why does this happen all of a sudden?

Comment: It seems `ows_blog` is not the proper field internal name. Double check that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks the your blog field is a URL field. A SharePoint URL field is built with 2 piece of information, the URL and the description. The first part is the URL. If your column is not a required field, then probably there's some data with no value hence you're getting the error "Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference".

You should re-write the part with proper data validation. Ex.

```
var blog = $(this).attr("ows_blog");
blog = blog ? blog.split(",")[0] : '#';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: As per OP `$(this).attr("ows_blog")` itself is returning null

Comment: It will return null if the value is null or the field doesn't exist. Thus a validation will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. With your validation suggested the slider worked and show undefined field on an image. I filled the value needed and it worked without producing any errors. Again thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: glad it helped. You can do similar validation for other fields too.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1:**

If `ows_blog` is having a null value

Than

```
null.split(",")
```

causes: *Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference*

Please check the value of ($(this).attr("ows_blog")) first.

**Solution 2:**

The quotes may be single instead of double or the tag uppercase.

**Note** : *Look in the console for what Chrome actually uses*

Comment: Yes the console.log(j(this).attr("ows_blog")); returns undefined value. I will try the single quotes but I have a feeling it won't work. Something has changed for some reason , but I haven't changed anything for months